# How can I link Historian Data to Insigth Control? in Wonderware

Tags: wonderware, historian

Insight control isn't displaying any data in wonderware even though tags are configured and chosen to point at them, and also data is historized. I'm not sure if I am missing any configuration. I've tried to use a trend control symbol and it doesn't show inside the pane when i drag it inside, but it does when i insert it on the pane.

I've added symbols to try to use it, but neither trend or insight app control show any data.

Comment: Does the Historian status show running on the System Management Console? Does it have the tags listed in the configuration options?

Comment: Yes, everything is running, but when i use the insight app control i just get a blank empty pane